# How to resize a div, within a parent-div, with parentdiv also resizing?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm fairly new to jQuery, but I like it a lot! Thumbs up to the developers! :)

My question is about the resizable function. The situation is as follows:

I have a div (parent-div), and within I have 5 other divs (directly next to each other, let's call them div-a through div-e). The parent-div represents a timespan (the longer it is, the more time it represents), and the five childrendiv's represent the five stages within that timespan.

Now, I want to be able to resize (let's say) child-div-c (the fase it represents takes more time). The div's D and E must shift to the left while i resize C, because their fases are just happening later, not shorter or longer. The parent-div must resize as well when i'm resizing C, because the total timespan will be longer.

I hope this is clear. The questions are:

How to move divs next to the resized div?
How to resize the parent div?

I am aware of the $(".selector).resizable ({}) event, and I got that working. But when I have 2 div's next to eachother, and I'm resizing one of them, it's not moving allong.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Despite this question was downvoted, I have the answer found and made a JSfiddle. See  my comment on the accepted answer.

The answer to my second question was this:

```
$(".selector").resizable( {
       resize: function(event, ui) {
            var widthTotal = 0;
            $(".travelcontainer > .travelfase").each(function(index, element) {
                widthTotal = $(this).innerWidth() + widthTotal;
            });
});
```

Hope this will help someone else as well :)

Comment: I believe using `width:100%` might help.

Comment: I think this was a pretty good question and was pretty complex for someone new to jQuery. He clearly demonstrated that he had thought this question through, was polite and thanked people for helping ahead of time, and, as he is new to jQuery, this is a pretty advanced project. I do not understand how or why people would give this question a downgrade, especially since this user is so new to SO.

Comment: @DorianGray: Which div should have that property in their css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/MjSfy/1/ it's pretty straight forward. Just align the child-divs with `float:left` or `display:inline-block`. Then whenever you change the width of one child-div the parent will adjust as well.

**Update:**

Use something like this to set the width of a div at runtime:

```
$("#div-a").css("width", "50px");​
```

Updated fiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/MjSfy/2/ and http://jsfiddle.net/MjSfy/3/

Comment: this is a nice visual example, but can you give some of the JS that you would use? I think his issue is more on the jQuery side of things

Comment: Thank you very much! I've succesfully applied this to make it work:

http://jsfiddle.net/MjSfy/4/

Funny thing is it doesn't work in jsfiddle, but it does when I put it in Dreamweaver. I don't know why, but it does. I post it here for people with the same problem :)

Comment: Glad that it helped you. On a side note: it is good practice to close a question (accept the most helpful answer) when your problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

If your child divs are being displayed using `float:left` or `display:inline-block` you shouldn't have to do anything to move the children after the resizing a preceding child.

If your parent div has a fixed width, you'll have to calculate the total of the children and set (or animate) that manually.